# Left join in two tables unrelated with JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a problem with creating a query in `JPQL` to join two tables `Table1` and `Table2` by a field called `code` (make `LEFT JOIN`).

The problem is that my two entities don't have the relations with JPA (and I need to do it that way).

I searched for a solution but I have not found it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the entity manager perform a native query. See [this page section "Utilizing Native SQL Queries"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html)

So your code would look like this:

```
List<SOME_DATA_TYPE> list = (List<SOME_DATA_TYPE>)em.createNativeQuery
  ("SELECT * FROM table1 a join talbl2 b on a.somefiedd = b.somefield " ,    some.package.name.SOME_DATA_TYPE.class)
                              .getResultList();
```

Technically not JPQL but still JPA. It's an idea. 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use JPQL if you are not using the properly entity relationships, but you could use native queries instead, consider using them to solve your requirement.